# Why is there a “Kingdom” note in Matthew 2:2?

Tags: kingdom, christology

What does this note mean? Does it say Christ is a King and also a Kingdom?

Note *a* next to Matthew 2:2 in the King James Scofield Study Bible is as follows: Magi came to Bethlehem..

> Saying, Where is he that is born *a*King of the Jews? for we have seen his star in the east, and are come to worship him.

*a - Kingdom* (Mt 2:6 Lk 1:31-33, 1Cor 15:24)

---

Referred verses:

Matthew 2:6

> And thou Bethlehem, in the land of Juda, art not the least among the princes of Juda: for out of thee shall come a Governor, that shall rule my people Israel.

Luke 1:31-33

> 31 And, behold, thou shalt conceive in thy womb, and bring forth a son, and shalt call his name Jesus. 32 He shall be great, and shall be called the Son of the Highest: and the Lord God shall give unto him the throne of his father David: 33 And he shall reign over the house of Jacob for ever; and of his kingdom there shall be no end.

1 Corinthians 15:24

> 24 Then cometh the end, when he shall have delivered up the kingdom to God, even the Father; when he shall have put down all rule and all authority and power.

---

Possibly (but probably not) related question below about:

1 Corinthians 15

> 23 But every man in his own order: Christ the firstfruits; afterward they that are Christ's at his coming.

> 24 Then cometh the end, when he shall have delivered up the kingdom to God, even the Father; when he shall have put down all rule and all authority and power.

> 25 For he must reign, till he hath put all enemies under his feet.

> 26 The last enemy that shall be destroyed is death.

[What does "he delivers the kingdom to God the Father" mean in 1 Corinthians 15:24?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9086/what-does-he-delivers-the-kingdom-to-god-the-father-mean-in-1-corinthians-152)

Comment: Serfdom has been obliterated: does that mean that all serfs perished, or that serfdom has been abolished ? Same for kingdom, denoting both the quality of being a ruler, as well as the domain over which it is exerted; alternately, think of dominion, meaning both rule and realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the simple facts:

- In Matt 2:2, the operative word is βασιλεύς = "king"
- In Luke 1:33 and 1 Cor 15:24, the operative word is βασιλεία = "kingdom, sovereignty, royal power".

There are a variety of cognate words available in Greek including:

- βασίλειον = "palace" (noun)
- βασίλειος = "royal" (adjective)
- βασιλεύω = "reign over" (verb)
- βασιλικός = "royal" (adjective)
- βασίλισσα = "queen" (noun)

However, in Matt 2:2, we have "king".  I presume that the note in the Scofield Bible is to references that define what kingdom Jesus were rule over, namely, the "kingdom of heaven/God" as distinct from any earthly kingdom.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it doesnt mean anything profound, just saying he has a kingdom or something awkward and imperfectly expressed. Or convention within an ongoing list and style that I haven’t picked up on. No deep, special meaning. || Royal power and sovereignty are not synonymous with “kingdom” imo.