1 Corinthians 15:24-28. If God is not included under subjection to the Son, and the Son becomes subjected to the Father, then how can the Son be God?
1 Corinthians 15:24-28 (NIV)

Then the end will come, when he hands over the kingdom to God the
Father after he has destroyed all dominion, authority and power. For
he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet. The
last enemy to be destroyed is death. For he “has put everything under
his feet.” Now when it says that “everything” has been put under him,
it is clear that this does not include God himself, who put everything
under Christ. When he has done this, then the Son himself will be made
subject to Him who put everything under him, so that God may be all in
all.

If the Son hands over everything to God the Father after putting everything under his feet, and the Son absorbs himself with everything that has been subjected to him (which does not include God), then how can Jesus be God?

This specific question has never been asked before, so I hope to receive some answers.

This is a theological question for Christianity SX.

This question is similar to: What does "he delivers the kingdom to God the Father" mean in 1 Corinthians 15:24?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There already is a Q asking how to interpret the phrase "when he hands over the kingdom to his Father"  -with lots of answers about this matter of subjection. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9086/what-does-he-delivers-the-kingdom-to-god-the-father-mean-in-1-corinthians-152  Whether or not this Q is better suited to one site than to another is a point, but the whole matter has been asked about many times, with a huge number of answers related to whether Christ can be God, in view of these verses.

My question is very unique and unlike the other questions posed for the same verses.

13 Then Jesus came from Galilee to the Jordan to John, to be baptized by him. 14 John would have prevented him, saying, “I need to be baptized by you, and do you come to me?” 15 But Jesus answered him, “Let it be so now, for thus it is fitting for us to fulfill all righteousness.” Then he consented.
The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (Matt 3:13–15). (2016). Crossway Bibles.

The Eternal One created the universe as His own temple. He built it for the six days and moved in/rested on the seventh.

19 By wisdom the Lord laid the earth’s foundations, by understanding
he set the heavens in place; 20 by his knowledge the watery depths
were divided, and the clouds let drop the dew. (Proverbs 3)
4 “Where were you when I laid the earth’s foundation? Tell me, if you
understand. 5 Who marked off its dimensions? Surely you know! Who
stretched a measuring line across it? 6 On what were its footings set,
or who laid its cornerstone— 7 while the morning stars sang together
and all the angels shouted for joy? 8 “Who shut up the sea behind
doors when it burst forth from the womb, 9 when I made the clouds its
garment and wrapped it in thick darkness, 10 when I fixed limits for
it and set its doors and bars in place, 11 when I said, ‘This far you
may come and no farther; here is where your proud waves halt’? (Job
38)

The building of the tabernacle in the wilderness followed the blueprint of the cosmic temple. It was a symbolic picture of the universe.
God from the very beginning had the will to rule His creation through priestly mediators. He made humanity to rule the world on His behalf. He planted Adam and Eve in the garden, telling them to keep it and expand it over the rest of the creation (be fruitful and multiply). That plan was derailed by the devil. Or it seemed that way for a while. But who is able to resist God's will? The project was put back on tracks by Jesus. What was impossible for a man, was accomplished by God Himself, incarnated in human body. The Father brings the whole world to Himself and restores humanity as His representatives in creation through Christ.

21 For since death came through a man, the resurrection of the dead
comes also through a man. 22 For as in Adam all die, so in Christ all
will be made alive.  23 But each in turn: Christ, the firstfruits;
then, when he comes, those who belong to him. 24 Then the end will
come, when he hands over the kingdom to God the Father after he has
destroyed all dominion, authority and power. 25 For he must reign
until he has put all his enemies under his feet. 26 The last enemy to
be destroyed is death. 27 For he “has put everything under his feet.”
Now when it says that “everything” has been put under him, it is clear
that this does not include God himself, who put everything under
Christ. 28 When he has done this, then the Son himself will be made
subject to him who put everything under him, so that God may be all in
all. (1 Corinthians 15)
3 Praise be to the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has
blessed us in the heavenly realms with every spiritual blessing in
Christ. 4 For he chose us in him before the creation of the world to
be holy and blameless in his sight. In love 5 he predestined us for
adoption to sonship through Jesus Christ, in accordance with his
pleasure and will— 6 to the praise of his glorious grace, which he has
freely given us in the One he loves. 7 In him we have redemption
through his blood, the forgiveness of sins, in accordance with the
riches of God’s grace 8 that he lavished on us. With all wisdom and
understanding, 9 he made known to us the mystery of his will according
to his good pleasure, which he purposed in Christ, 10 to be put into
effect when the times reach their fulfillment—to bring unity to all
things in heaven and on earth under Christ. 11 In him we were also
chosen, having been predestined according to the plan of him who works
out everything in conformity with the purpose of his will, 12 in order
that we, who were the first to put our hope in Christ, might be for
the praise of his glory. 13 And you also were included in Christ when
you heard the message of truth, the gospel of your salvation. When you
believed, you were marked in him with a seal, the promised Holy
Spirit, 14 who is a deposit guaranteeing our inheritance until the
redemption of those who are God’s possession—to the praise of his
glory. 15 For this reason, ever since I heard about your faith in the
Lord Jesus and your love for all God’s people, 16 I have not stopped
giving thanks for you, remembering you in my prayers. 17 I keep asking
that the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the glorious Father, may give
you the Spirit of wisdom and revelation, so that you may know him
better. 18 I pray that the eyes of your heart may be enlightened in
order that you may know the hope to which he has called you, the
riches of his glorious inheritance in his holy people, 19 and his
incomparably great power for us who believe. That power is the same as
the mighty strength 20 he exerted when he raised Christ from the dead
and seated him at his right hand in the heavenly realms, 21 far above
all rule and authority, power and dominion, and every name that is
invoked, not only in the present age but also in the one to come. 22
And God placed all things under his feet and appointed him to be head
over everything for the church, 23 which is his body, the fullness of
him who fills everything in every way. (Ephesians 1)


There is a certain truth in your last paragraph. But you have missed the fact that the Father has created again, in Christ - a New Creation. And that, within an Everlasting Testament. His purposes ever were in the Son of His Love. and to this end is all that is new. The New Testament is not a reversion or a correction of that which was in Adam. It is altogether New, in another humanity (other than Adam) - the bringing of many sons to glory through a glorious Redemption (apolutrosis) and a final Restoration (apokatallasso) unto a fundamental Restitution (apokatastasis).

I did not say that Christ restores everything to what it originally was in the Book of Genesis. Of course, there is an obvious upgrade in the new creation. The world of Genesis 1 was very good, but had a room for improvement. On purpose. For example, humanity had to subdue the earth, and the heavenly beings were created to rule over the darkness. In the new creation, there is no darkness. And there is no sea, which is an ancient middle-eastern symbol of the chaos.

Ultimately, the new heaven and the new earth are presented as the refinement of the original creation, rather than a completely new and different thing.

I disagree but I shall leave it with you. Regards.

Take care my friend.
